# how to make a bone move (slide) on one axis while following another bone?

Tags: armature, bones, constraints

i want to make the lower piston slides along the larger cylinder. maybe there are other ways to achieve this?
[image: scheme]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the general situation, with any meshes, this isn't reasonable-- it's what physics are for.  But for your situation, where your drawings indicate that you're interested in the abstract sphere-and-plane situation, this is reasonable with bone constraints alone:

[image]

[image]

I've created a three bone IK chain, originating at the lower piston, continuing on with a bone the length of the spherical radius, then continuing on at a 90 degree angle to position of the cylinder.  This final bone has an IK target at the same angle, placed some distance away.  Not the hierarchy on the outliner.

The first bone in the IK chain is the only deforming bone in the chain.  Here, it is axis locked to rotate only in its Z axis (we don't want it rotating in Y and flipping the piston inside the cylinder.)  The second bone is also only allowed to rotate in its Z axis.  The final bone is not allowed to rotate in any axis-- all IK axes are locked.  But it is allowed to stretch (IK stretch on the bone is set to 1.0.)

[image]

The piston's angle is defined by the fact that the point that the sphere will touch the plane is always tangent to the sphere.  We have enforced that by placing the third bone at a right angle to the second bone and preventing any IK rotation of that third bone.

Comment: Thanks a lot for such detailed answer, Nathan! That's very interesting way so solve that. I have poked around in your file and I find a small flaw in this method
https://i.stack.imgur.com/mEo5j.jpg I used transformation constraint. Mapped from Z rotation (of piston_big_01) to Y location (using Z as a source axis) https://i.stack.imgur.com/a2HiN.jpg